# Visual Studio breakpoint don't get hit C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clang, llvm, breakpoints

I built llvm with clang using cmake to create the Visual studio `sln` file to debug it in windows. I'm using VS2017 with the v140 (Visual studio 2015) compiler compiled in `Debug` mode and x64. It compiled with 0 warnings.

I want to set a breakpoint at [here](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/960a40ec576f07b6fb196cc91d08abbcffbc04c0/lib/CodeGen/AsmPrinter/AsmPrinter.cpp#L2596) and I do so using Visual Studio but it never gets hit and the execution code definitely goes through that line because I put a `MessageBox` and I can see the pop up.

I've tried using [`DebugBreak`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679297%28VS.85%29.aspx) too but it crashes clang.

I've checked the two solutions clang and LLVMAsmPrinter (where the function i'm setting the breakpoint is) and they are compiled with as Debug with symbols.

LLVMAsmPrinter compiles to a `.lib` file.

I already tried to rebuild the project but not luck either :(

Why is the breakpoint not being hit. Is it because LLVMAsmPrinter is a different project within the same llvm Visual Studio solution

Thanks you all!

Comment: If you don't run the exe from the VS, then you need to attack to process. Another thing to look for is to compile in  debug mode.

Comment: Of course I did both things. Running clang from the debugger and as I said in the question compiling it in Debug mode.

Comment: Try 32 bit mode in VS

Comment: @Grantly why is that gonna make a difference?

Comment: I tried, just in case but same thing. I created the project with the LLVM_ENABLE_MODULE_DEBUGGING flag but still, no luck getting the BP hit. More ideas?

Comment: IF you place a breakpoint in visual studio, it should be a solid red circle. IF it turns white in the inside, that usually means that the debug info (.pdb) is out of date. Sometimes VS cannot find the pdb files on its own. Open module window( Debug->Windows->Modules), choose the proper module, rightclick and "Load symbol information" (Loosely translated from german language)

Comment: And do you link statically or dynamically to LLVM/Clang?

Comment: The circle is solid red. I built it with all the symbols. Regarding linking  It's generating .lib so it's statically linked. Does it matters? Thank you